# Añadir un método mediante el atributo prototype

Tags: javascript

Tengo una estructura de código a la que debo agregarle un método haciendo uso de **prototype** que devuelva en minúscula la cadena que le pase invoncando la función y obteniendo el resultado de la siguiente forma:

> senteces.format(“I’m Pablo”) // Result: i’m Pablo

Este es el bloque de código provisto:

```
let sentences = {
   word: "Hello ",

   connect(appender) {
       console.log(sentences.word + appender);
   },

   //Función que devuelve el resultado pero sin 
   format(formatting){
       console.log(formatting.toLowerCase());
   },
}

sentences.connect("World");       //muestra Hello World
sentences.format(“I’m Pablo”);   //Debería mostrar i’m Pablo
```

La función que creé para esto es **format** y devuelve el valor requerido poniendo con comilas simples la cadena, es decir, en vez de ser **senteces.format(“I’m Pablo”)** esribo **senteces.format('I’m Pablo')**.

He intentando utilizar de mil maneras **prototype** para el método format dentro del objeto sentences y el compilador me arroja TypeError, una de las formas como lo he implementado es esta:

> `prototype.toLowerString = function toLowerString (formatting) { console.log(toLowerString(formatting)); };`

**¿Cual es la manera correcta de utilizar protoype en Javascript?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos los objetos en JS heredan el prototipo Object, que tiene métodos como hasOwnProperty() y toString(), si querés agregar la funcion format() usando prototype en tu objeto:

```
let sentences = {
  word: "Hello ",
  connect(appender) {
    console.log(sentences.word + appender);
  }
}
```

Podes hacerlo de dos formas, la primero es usar `sentences.__proto__`:

```
sentences.__proto__.format = function(formatting){ 
  console.log(formatting.toLowerCase());
} 

sentences.format('I,m Pablo')
```

***proto** es una característica obsoleta que pronto será eliminada de los estándares  relevantes de la web, nos crea problemas de seguridad y se recomienda evitar su uso, tenes más detalles acá [**proto** MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#:%7E:text=The%20__proto__%20property%20is%20a%20simple%20accessor%20property,that%20does%20not%20consult%20Object.)*.

La manera correcta seria usando la propiedad `Object.getPrototypeOf(sentences)` para obtener el prototipo y agregarle la propiedad que queramos, más información sobre el método [**Object.getPrototypeOf()** MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(sentences).format = function(formatting){ 
  console.log(formatting.toLowerCase());
}

sentences.format('I,m Pablo')
```

Podes visualizar la función creada en el prototipo si volves a usar `Object.getPrototypeOf(sentences)` dentro de un `console.log()`.

De hecho hay otra forma y es definiendo nuestro propio prototipo, y luego lo establecemos en nuestro objeto con la propiedad [**Object.setPrototypeOf()** MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

```
const myPrototype = {
  format: function(formatting){
    console.log(formatting.toLowerCase())
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(sentences,myPrototype)
sentences.format('I,m Pablo')
```

De hecho modificar el prototipo de un objeto es una operación muy lenta para el navegador y el motor de JavaScript, si el rendimiento te preocupa podes usar `let sentences = Object.create(prototype)` que creara un nuevo objeto usando el objeto prototipo pasado por parámetros.

Comment: Excelente, gracias por todos los escenarios descritos, me ha ayudado mucho tu respuesta y las documentaciones que has aportado.